# Should I point out a mistake in recruiter's LinkedIn headline?

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process, mistakes

A recruiter I'm corresponding with has a grammar mistake in their LinkedIn headline. When I speak to them about potential roles should I point this out? Of course, as tactfully as possible.

On the one hand, if it were me I'd want to know because people, like me, who see the mistake will be judging, even if they are too polite to mention it. On the other hand there is a good chance that I'd just appear as a pompous jerk, potentially ruining any prospects.

What would be a suitably tactful way to approach it if I decide to let them know?

Comment: Only if you are applying for a position as a wisenheimer.

Comment: Does the job you are applying for contain any part where you would do that? For example Editor or Reviewer?

Comment: @nvoigt, The OP profile says "I have a PhD in Bioengineering from the University of Auckland. I write code, mainly in C++ and Python." So, he can certainly review code in C++ and Python (and also Bioengineering topics) among other things...

Answer (score 4):

I would just ignore that typo because it does not have a serious effect on anyone at this time.

Instead, I would focus more on learning about their company, the job, and how to get an interview with their company.

You are the one looking for a job, and you should make sure your resume and LinkedIn profile have no typo, vocabulary, and grammar mistakes.

On the other hand, the recruiter is not looking for a job, and no one is scrutinizing their resume and LinkedIn profile.

---

I know you are trying to help the recruiter. But, I would suggest that the best thing you could do is to focus on your job search.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is a bit different, based on that I would like to know immediately of any such errors.  But not every one takes criticism well.

If I was getting along with the recruiter when meeting face to face, only then I would say something like "By the way, did you know there is a **minor** error on your post".  If they ask for details, then I would point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following the principle of least astonishment, it's best to do it **after** you've concluded your professional interaction as a recruiter and a candidate.

It's common for a recruiter to help the candidate with their resume, not so much the other way around. Once you're done with the recruitment part, you're either colleagues or just two minimally-familiar people, and it's a normal interaction.

People have different attitude towards grammar corrections; best not to bring it into a context where it's not expected.

Comment: Maybe, it best to wait till the OP gets the job, and then tell the recruiter about the typo in his "thank you" note to the recruiter.